# try ing to obtain computer detail from linux ldapsearch command

Tags: ldap

I'm trying to obtain computer detail from linux ldapsearch command

I am using this command to get the userid info.

```
ldapsearch -t -x -D "ashu@example.com" -W -H ldaps://ldap.example.com:3269 -b "DC=example,DC=com"  "samaccountname=<USERNAME>" | grep memberOf
```

Now i want to get the info for computer name.

```
ldapsearch -t -x -D "ashu@example.com" -W -H ldaps://ldap.example.com:3269 -b "DC=example,DC=com"  "(&(objectcategory=computer)(description=INXXXXX.example.com))"
```

Can someone tell me what wrong this to get the computer description

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why you would expect to find values within the description field?

A LDAP Query filter (no mater linux or otherwise) similar to:

```
(&(cn=INXXXXX)(sAMAccountType=805306369))
```

Should work. So the full command line query I used looks similar to:

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://example.com:3269 -x -D "EXAMPLE\USERID" -W -b "DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM" -s sub -a always -z 1000 "(&(cn=WAPP000167)(sAMAccountType=805306369))"
```

If you have populated description with the value "INXXXXX.example.com" then you search should work.

Using (sAMAccountType=805306369) vs (objectcategory=computer) just always seems to be faster. (Seems like I read this somewhere).